# rocksdb in multithreaded environment

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, synchronization, rocksdb

I'm using rocksdb in a multithreaded environment.

All of my threads are doing `get()`, `put()` and `merge()` operations, potentially with the same keys.

Is rocks providing me with any built in synchronization? Is it configurable? I've gone through documentation and source code, but couldn't figure it out for certain.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such synchronization.

You're only guaranteed that `get`, `put` and `merge` operations are atomic. However, if you are trying to read and write the same key-value pair in a multi-threaded environment, the operations' order is NOT determined. You have to do the synchronization yourself.

Comment: What about the callbacks of merge operator?

Comment: @Mugen `merge` is an encapsulation of read-modify-write pattern. It's guaranteed that the merge operation, i.e. the merge callback, is atomic. However, you still need to do the synchronization among several `merge`, `put`, and `get` operations by yourself.

Comment: @for_stack Is it ok to call open() without locks? I have multiple (Python) threads, each opening a db, sometimes the same one. I lock around put() but not sure about open()